# Выделить из строки числа и знаки операций

Tags: c++, массивы, стек, польская-запись

На вход с клавиатуры подаётся строки вида: + * - 5 8 7 + 12 879  (конкретнее, это прямая польская запись)

Мне нужно записать их в массив (в этом же порядке) Хранить собираюсь как массив строк. (Может есть идеи получше?, можно пользоваться любыми контейнерами). Было бы проще, если числа были бы только в диапазоне 0-9.

P.S. На самом деле это ползадачи, далее нужно эту самую польскую запись вычислить. Так как она прямая, нужно идти справа налево. Поэтому мне нужно строку где-то хранить.

Comment: не надо парсить и хранить ввод, пишите сразу калькулятор

Answer (score 1):

Если вводимые токены разделены пробелами, то вы можете использовать следующий подход

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::string input;

    std::getline( std::cin, input );

    std::istringstream is( input );

    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    std::copy( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ),
               std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
               std::back_inserter( tokens ) );

    for ( const auto &s : tokens ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Если ввести строку

```
+ * - 5 8 7 + 12 879
```

то вывод будет ей соответствовать

```
+ * - 5 8 7 + 12 879
```

Если в дальнейшем вам нужно обрабатывать созданный вектор в обратном порядке, то вы можете использовать его реверсивные итераторы, или сразу же реверсировать вектор, используя стандартный алгоритм `std::reverse`. Например,

```
std::reverse( tokens.begin(), tokens.end() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы, не мудрствуя лукаво, использовал структуру с полями `int` и `char`, записывал бы сразу в стек и вычислял.

Как-то так (писано на коленке, неоптимально и без обработки ошибок, чтоб идею пояснить). Хранить в массиве строк, полагаю, нецелесообразно. Стек - *естественный* выбор для обратной польской записи...

```
struct Item
{
    int  i = 0;
    char c = 0;
};

int main() 
{
    string input;
    getline(cin,input);
    stack<Item> st;
    for(int i = 0, end = input.length(); i < end; ++i)
    {
        switch(input[i])
        {
        case ' ': break;
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '*':
        case '/':
            {
                Item it;
                it.c = input[i];
                st.push(it);
                // cout << "Push " << it.c << endl;
                break;
            }
        default:
            if (!isdigit(input[i]))
            {
                cerr << "Wrong symbol\n";
                return 1;
            }
            Item it;
            char * pos;
            it.i = strtol(&input[i],&pos,10);
            i += pos-&input[i];
            st.push(it);
            // cout << "Push " << it.i << endl;
        }
    }

    while(!st.empty())
    {
        int i1  = st.top().i; st.pop();
        if (st.empty())
        {
            cout << "Result: " << i1 << endl;
            break;
        }
        int i2  = st.top().i; st.pop();
        char op = st.top().c; st.pop();
        switch(op)
        {
        case '+': i1 += i2; break;
        case '-': i1 -= i2; break;
        case '*': i1 *= i2; break;
        case '/': i1 /= i2; break;
        default:
            cerr << "Wrong expression\n";
            return 1;
        }
        Item it;
        it.i = i1;
        st.push(it);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Да, тут числа считаются положительными; просто не заморачивался отрицательными, чтоб не усложнять.

Comment: @минусатор: А почему минус?

Comment: @VladD Судя по всему, потому что я взял тайм-аут на написание кода :)